# Python - how to find next max date

Tags: python, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe like this `(1-Jan-2020, 1-Feb-2020, 1-Mar-2020)`. Datetime module gives us Max and min function to find the max and min date which is `1-Jan-2020` and `1-Mar-2020`.

I tried other options of making this dataframe to convert to list and remove max date using `list.remove` function. But this makes list empty. can anyone please help me to get the output `1-Feb-2020`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.nlargest` method provided by pandas to get first `n` largest elements from your dataframe.

This returns a list of `n` largest elements.

Just fetch the last element of the list and your work should be done.

Something like this :

```
df['dates'].nlargest(2).iloc[-1]
```

Since you do not have any column name, consider this example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
               'month': [2, 3],
               'day': [4, 5]})
dataframe = pd.to_datetime(df)

second_max_date = dataframe.nlargest(2).iloc[-1]
```

Comment: I dont have any column name for my dataframe.. the above piece of code requires column name

Comment: How are you accessing the dates column ?

Comment: what I have is dataframe=pd.to_datetime(df,format="%d-%M-%Y",errors="ignore") and this df has (1-Jan-2020, 1-Feb-2020, 1-Mar-2020). when I access max(dataframe) - it returns 1-Jan-2020. and min(dataframe) - it returns 1-Feb-2020. I tried so many ways to get 1-Feb-2020 but nothing worked

Comment: Use the same method you are using to find `max` and `min`. Instead of `max`, `min` use `.nlargest` and that should work.

Comment: "dtype {dtype}".format(method=method, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object ---- getting this error mesg while using .nlargest

Comment: Try this: `dataframe.nlargest(2).iloc[-1]`

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: dataframe.nlargest(2).iloc[-1]  - tried this and got the same error     "dtype {dtype}".format(method=method, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object

Comment: There is some problem with the `df` you have created and what I am assuming. Please share the full code with print for variable df.